# Django form in the base template. How to display validation error?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I use Django 1.8.14. I have `Search` form on every page of my website. I pass `Search` form to base template through context processor. Each time form sends data to `/search/` view. And there is a problem. Django raises `ValidationError` on form, but it doesn't display anywhere. What is the correct way to display form errors in template, when form passes to base template through context processor and sends data to one view?

**form.py**:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(required = True,
                          max_length=255,
                          widget = forms.TextInput({'class':'form-control', 'type':'search','required':''})
)

   def clean_search(self):
     search = self.cleaned_data.get("search")
     regex = myregex
     if not re.match(regex, search):
         print("ValidationError")
         raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please enter a valid value')
     return search
```

context processor:

```
from myproject.forms import SearchForm

def form_context(request):
   context_dict = {}
   context_dict['search_form'] = SearchForm()
   return(context_dict)
```

my base template:

```
 <form method="post" action="/search/">               
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ search_form.non_field_errors }}
     {{ search_form.errors }}
     {{ search_form.search }}
     {{ search_form.search.errors }}        
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-find">Search</button>
 </form>
```

my seach view:

```
def search(request, template):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if search_form.is_valid():
           domen = search_form.cleaned_data['search']
           try:
              site = SitePage.objects.get(domen=domen)
              path="/"+site.domen +"/"
              return HttpResponseRedirect(path)
           except:
            site = None
        else:
            print search_form.errors
return render(request, template, context_dict)
```

Comment: I cant see how the template receives your search from from your `search` view. The context_dict is not populated... Is there another piece of code not shown here? Otherwise it might help to add `context_dict={"search_form":search_form}` to your view function.

Comment: Many things are wrong here. Please study django tutorial from their website, because I don't quite understand why you're using context processor instead for passing validated form to the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Django is raising `validation error` how you want it to and now all you need is to **display** that validation error on your `html templates` then i suppose what you are looking for is **Django Messages**

See the official documentation for the same -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's exactly what I need!

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the form once it is bound to the data (the POST request) and validated; right now your context only has a blank form which is why no errors are being displayed.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def search(request, template):
    search_form = SearchForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if search_form.is_valid():
       domen = search_form.cleaned_data['search']
       results = SitePage.objects.filter(domen=domen)
       if results.exists():
          return redirect('/{}/'.format(results.domen))

    return render(request, template, {'form': search_form})
```